# DRF: to_representation() called twice on serializer update()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My site has a Vue frontend with a DRF backend. I have a model with a multi-value field that looks like this:

```
    stages = StageSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )
```

In the `to_representation()` method, I process the stages data into three different elements to facilitate features for the frontend.

```
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        results = super().to_representation(instance)
        return render_stages(results)
```

The problem is, when I post (PATCH actually) to an update view, which ends up calling the `update()` method of the serializer, the `to_representation()` method seems to be called twice.  I could post the code from `render_stages()`, but I don't see how that could be causing the problem.  Suffice to say that it takes this, from the call to `super().to_representation()`:

```
{
   .
   . other fields
   .
   "stages": [
       {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "To Do"
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "In Progress"
       },
       {
           "id": 3,
           "name": "Done"
       }
   ]
}
```

...and turns it into this:

```
{
   "stages": [
       "To Do",
       "In Progress",
       "Done"
   ],
   "stages_order": "1,2,3",
   "stages_data": [
       {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "To Do",
           "order": 1
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "In Progress",
           "order": 2
       },
       {
           "id": 3,
           "name": "Done",
           "order": 3
       }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, the format of the "stages" element changes after the first pass through `to_representation()` from a list of dicts to a list of strings.  So when `to_representation()` gets called a second time, it raises an exception.

On a list view, it only gets called once.  It's just on an update view that it gets called twice.  Can someone explain why that's happening?

**Update:** More details:

The view.  The settings model only has one row - pk=1 - so this is a departure from the norm.

```
class SettingsUpdate(ViewMetaMixin, UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SettingsSaveSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, CanAccessEndpoint)

    queryset = Settings.objects.none()

    def get_object(self):
        obj = Settings.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.patch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({
            'results': response.data,
            'messages': [
                {
                    'message': _('Settings updated.'),
                    'message_type': 'status',
                }
            ]
        })
```

The serializer:

```
class SettingsSaveSerializer(SettingsSerializer):
    stages = StageSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        results = super().to_representation(instance)
        return render_stages(results)

    ...validations omitted...

    ...create method omitted...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        stages = get_initial_data_field(self.initial_data, 'stages', many=True)
        if stages is not None:      # Only process "stages" if it's present in form data
            validated_data['stages_order'] = Stage.objects.save_stages(instance, stages)

        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: That is weird. Can you post your full view and the full serializers that are being used in the update flow? There may be something that's forcing it to be called twice.

Comment: My bad. For each of our models, we define an XxxxSerializer and an XxxxSaveSerializer. That allows us to, for example, include a many-to-one field in the SaveSerializer, for updating purposes, that we don't want to include in the regular serializer. Saves a lot of overhead for list views that don't need the many-to-one field data. So the SettingsSerializer and SettingsSaveSerializer both originally had to_representation(), but later I decided it would be easier/cleaner to subclass SettingsSaveSerializer from SettingsSerializer. So "Save" was invoking super(), which ran to_representation twice.

Comment: Since this is not an issue that others are likely to have (or likely to search for), should I delete this question?

Comment: I think it's fine to leave up.